# Before launch, run external tool asynchronously?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13, external-tools

Is it possible to create run configurations where it doesn't wait for the external tool to exit before launching?

I'm currently trying to get Dart's `pub serve` to run on my project directory before opening the Dartium browser on `localhost:8080` but it seems that it's just waiting for `pub` to exit before it does. Which won't happen as `pub serve` continues to show output from the local server.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I'm just here to report that I can't get IntelliJ *not* to execute a before launch task asynchronously...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the best answer, but this should work:

Create a wrapper script, say `pub_async.bat`, that asynchronously calls `pub.bat` with correct command line arguments and returns immediately.

You may lose the ability to "stop" the process, and so shutting down / cleaning up may need to be handled in a different way.

Comment: Good idea, some times the simplest workaround is the best solution. :)